# Toggle Stack Overflow Chat Sidebar

Tags: script, chat

### Screenshot

On toggle show sidebar:

[image: Show]

On toggle hide sidebar:

[image: Hide]

### About

The sidebar will be automatically hidden. When you want to see the sidebar, take the mouse to the right edge of the screen and the sidebar will appear. Then as long as you keep the mouse in the sidebar area, the sidebar will stay.

#### License

It is free and open source. Licensed under MIT License.

#### Download

You can download it from [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinmmansour/7549a7de8ca7c23f39dcf9e44eb2b750).

#### Platform

Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Microsoft Edge. Windows, macOS, Linux (All distros).

### Contact

I created this script and you can ping me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends).

### Code

I used JavaScript to build this project, and you can contribute to the script in [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinmmansour/7549a7de8ca7c23f39dcf9e44eb2b750). And feature-requests and bug in answers under the question.

Comment: How about adding a keyboard shortcut for toggling? Some people prefer using keyboard as much as possible and the mouse as little as possible - by adding the shortcut you can accommodate the user case of those users. Something like a single shortcut that flips the sidebar state

Comment: @OlegValter Great Idea. I will work on Ctrl + Q to flip the sidebar state. Thank you. :)

Comment: Awesome -  keeps the SO chats experience clean.